# Скролл и hover на пункт меню при нажатии на ссылку

Tags: javascript, css

Как сделать, чтобы при клике по ссылке на странице выполнялся скролл к главному меню в хедере, и в выпадающем меню раскрывалось это же меню, как будто пользователь  выполнил :hover на него?

Answer (score 0):

Примера кода нету, поэтому ответ очень в общих чертах, но все же

Пролистать к шапке можно с помощью якоря (шапке нужно дать id, а у ссылки указать href='#выбранный_id')
А по поводу открытия меню, нужно в css создать класс, при котором это меню будет открыто и при клике по нужной ссылке присваивать этот класс меню